# cudaMalloc segmentation fault high values

Tags: cuda, segmentation-fault

**First the error :**
Segmentation Fault (at the highlighted cudaMalloc line if I make a > approximately 61432)

```
unsigned int xarray[a];
unsigned int *dev_a;
int result[33*a];
int *dev_result;

**cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_a,a * sizeof(unsigned int));**

cudaMemcpy(dev_a,xarray,a*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

kernel<<<a,66>>>(dev_a,dev_result);

cudaMemcpy(result,dev_result,33*a*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

The reason why I mentioned 'approximately' above is because sometimes it works when a = 61432 and sometimes it doesn't. I am not able to understand why.

Also, this is only for a launch of 1D grid of blocks. My intent is to launch a 3D grid [a*a*a].

Comment: You can't expect the compiler to be able to statically allocate an array (`result`) that large on the stack. Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: You want to allocate a `61432³` grid? Where did you get a GPU with 8 petabytes memory??

Comment: I used malloc instead and it seems to solved the problem. Thanks !

Comment: leftaroundabout - can I not use dim3 blocks(65535,65535,65535) and launch kernel<<<blocks,66>>>(dev_abc,dev_result) !?!?!??!
Where dev_abc (65535 x 65535 x 65535) ?!?!?! I want to max the GPU

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think I understood what you meant, there is not enough memory on the GPU for utilizing full 65535x65535x65535 dimensions, for my problem at hand I can go upto say 220x220x200.

Answer (score 1):

You code is segfaulting because the array `result` is too large. In practice, you can't really expect to statically allocate an array of size `33 * 61432` on the stack.

Instead, use a `std::vector` to dynamically allocate the array and pass a pointer to the pointer's data to `cudaMemcpy`:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<int> result(33 * 1);
...
cudaMemcpy(&result[0], dev_result, 33 * a * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```